# Getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Command failed

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, office-interop

I have used `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` for converting word to pdf, which is working fine on my local machine.

But when I moved the exe files to server (server has microsoft office installed), it's showing me below exception.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Command failed

   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveAs(Object& FileName, Objec
t& FileFormat, Object& LockComments, Object& Password, Object& AddToRecentFiles,
 Object& WritePassword, Object& ReadOnlyRecommended, Object& EmbedTrueTypeFonts,
 Object& SaveNativePictureFormat, Object& SaveFormsData, Object& SaveAsAOCELette
r, Object& Encoding, Object& InsertLineBreaks, Object& AllowSubstitutions, Objec
t& LineEnding, Object& AddBiDiMarks)
   at PDF_Converter.Program.ConvertWordToPdf(String sInputFile, String sOutputFi
le) in D:\Work\HtmlToPDF_Converter\HTML_PDF_Converter\IMAGE_PDF_Converter\Progra
m.cs:line 89
   at PDF_Converter.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Work\HtmlToPDF_Converter\H
TML_PDF_Converter\IMAGE_PDF_Converter\Program.cs:line 30
```

Below is my code for conversion.

```
private static void ConvertWordToPdf(string sInputFile, string sOutputFile)
        {

            // Create a new Microsoft Word application object
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            word.Visible = false;
            word.ScreenUpdating = false;


            if (File.Exists(sInputFile))
            {

                FileInfo wordFile = new FileInfo(sInputFile);

                // Cast as Object for word Open method
                Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

                // Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc.Activate();

                object outputFileName = sOutputFile;
                object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

                // Save document into PDF Format
                doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                    ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                // Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
                // doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
                // correct Close method.                
                object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc = null;

            }

            // word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
            // the correct Quit method.
            ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            word = null;
        }
```

Is there anything which I'm missing?

Comment: Is the same office version installed at the server?

Comment: Google "word saveas error 4198", lots and lots of hits.  Fwiw, never run an Office program on a server, the machine will keel over in a hurry.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes both have same 2007 version

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25254605/1768303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error as you mentioned.

Check if office installed on the server does have pdf type in "Save as" options?

Install **`2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS`** from below link if not available.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7

I hope it will resolve the error.